# Clipping of overflowing div inside foreignObject during translate in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, d3.js

I'm using D3.js to render `g` SVG elements, each containing a `foreignObject` so that I can attach a styled `div` text. The HTML looks like this:

```
<g class=node ...>

    <circle ...></circle>
    <clipPath ...>
        <circle ...></circle>
    </clipPath>
    <image ...></image>

    <foreignObject ...>
        <div ...>...</div>
    </foreignObject>

</g>
```

There are 60 of these elements contained in a parent `g` element which is translated with `transform: translate(...)` when the user scrolls.

Here, the `foreignObject` has `height=1` and `width=1` with `overflow: visible`. This allows the contained `div` to be sized based on the text it contains.

This works fine on Chrome and Edge (and Safari if I remember correctly), however on Firefox, the `div` element inside `foreignObject` gets 'clipped' when I call `translate` on the parent `g` element. The image below shows the correct rendering:

[image: correct rendering]

And the image below shows the rendering during `translate`.

[image]

I suspect this has something to do with the `width` and `height` of the `g` elements (i.e. `node` class) because the clipping occurs outside the boundary of `g`. How would I fix this? I've thought of using JavaScript to modify the `width` and `height` of `g`, but these attributes are based on the rendering which I don't know in advance.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is fixed by setting the `width` and `height` properties of `foreignObject` to `100%`.

Comment: I found a same solution, but not suit my problem because I attach an event to parent g, and with 100% width of foreign element, I have the interactive zone too wide. Found an alternative of why works on chrome and opera but not FF ?

Comment: wow, for anyone landing here, thanks to @duncster94 mentioning the property *overflow* I found Chrome and Opera default on another value than FF. You can use auto or others and may achieve same results as width = 100%.